# Should I include both Lag 1 and Lag 4 in this autoregressive model?

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, autoregressive, seasonality

**Question Background**: Thomas Anderson, CFA, is a  research analyst at Frank Capital Consultants, a provider of statistical modeling and financial advice to clients globally. Thomas is working on the analysis of a company, RWC Inc., a manufacturer of water pipes. He examines the company’s sales and runs an autoregressive model to identify any observable pattern in the sales data for the past five years. The model uses a lag one variable.

Here I have an autoregressive model intended to identify any observable pattern in the sales of some company, RWC Inc.

This first model uses 1 lag variable and the results are here:
[image]

Then I also have another autoregressive model made by including Lag 1 and Lag 4 with results here:

[image]

And my question is which of the following models would best describe the sales of RWC? Is it

A: $X_t = b_0 + b_1X_{t-1}$

B: $X_t = b_0 + b_1X_{t-1} + b_2X_{t-4}$

C: $X_t = b_0 + b_1X_{t-4}$

I assumed it was B since only B contains both Lag 1 and Lag 4 and because Lag 1 is significantly different from 0, so perhaps Lag 4 also being significantly different 0 would help to offset the invalidity of the first model. Is this thinking correct and if not, which model is best?

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking yourself questions like "Are the data quarterly?"

Comment: I've added background information to the question above. Well it's the sales data for a company over the past five years, so perhaps the data is not quarterly, but annual.  I've given all the information I have concerning the problem.  How, specifically, would this data affect which lags I should include in the model though? In general I'm struggling to understand how to tell when to include lags in a model like this.